# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. AOInitiliaze

Tags: arcobjects, .net, arcgis-runtime, wcf

I create a WCF Service.

When I try to Initialize ArcGIS License with AOInitialize I get error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

```
public void initializeArcGISLicenses()
    {

            RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
            AoInitialize ao = new AoInitialize();
            if (ao.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced) == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable) //Error is here
                ao.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
           /* else if (ao.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic) == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable)
                ao.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic);
            else if (ao.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard) == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable)
                ao.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard);*/
    }
```

What's the problem?
Sorry for my English.